# Python division: // vs math.floor

Tags: python, rounding, division

Нello! Consider the following in python:

```
import math

num = # Any float...
div = # Any float...

result_1 = math.floor(num / div)
result_2 = num // div

are_equal = result_1 == result_2
print(are_equal)
```

I have heard that `are_equal` should always be `True`, no matter the values of `num` and `div`.

Strangely, I've found a case where this doesn't hold: `num = 146097.0` and `div = 365.2425`.

**Is this surprising? Are there many examples like this?**

**Why doesn't `(146097.0 // 365.2425) == math.floor(146097.0  / 365.2425)`?**

Comment: Floating-point error. `/` may return "exactly" 400, but that is apparently after rounding an internal value that is just a bit less than 400. `//`, on the other hand, is flooring the internal value, not the rounded one.

Comment: That's interesting! So why does python discard information, and produce a value apart from the internal value for `/`? Does the internal value have a higher bit depth? Is there any way to see the internal value?

Comment: This may shed some light on the case: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/7py9va/this_buggy_python3_floor_division/

Comment: It's not discarding information; it doesn't have the information to begin with. A floating point value is a rational number whose denominator is a power of 2, but 0.2425 is not a power of 2.  As a result, `div` is just a close approximation that is, apparently, slightly less more than 365.2425.

Comment: I thought the Decimal module should not be subject to floating point errors when the numbers are integer-divisible. Any student with a piece of pencil and paper can see that 146097 / 365.2425 is exactly 400. It took me by surprise that the decimal module could not handle this division the same way.

Comment: A million apologies if I'm going in circles now: it looks to me like python *does* have the information to begin with: it knows that `146097.0  / 365.2425` is *exactly* `400.0`

Comment: That's because `Decimal('365.2425')` is not equivalent to the floating point value generated by the literal `365.2425`.

Comment: Compare `Decimal('365.2425')` and `Decimal(365.2425)`.

Comment: You are right! Decimal(div) prints as Decimal('365.24250000000000682121026329696178436279296875'). Interesting.

Comment: See e.g. also https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html for the binary value.

Comment: To add to my comment above: that converter is only 32 bit; there'll be a 64 bit one with similar principle, which should show a closer actual value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`div` isn't exactly 365.2425; it's a floating-point approximation of the rational number 3652425/10000.

```
>>> 365.2425.as_integer_ratio()
(6425414011327611, 17592186044416)  # Not (3652425, 10000) or (146097, 400)
```

As a result, the ratio isn't *exactly* 400, but something just a little bit less that `/` rounds to 400. `//`, however, floors the internal value. The `Decimal` type provides arbitrary precision, so you can see the effect of using the approximation generated by `365.2425`:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(365.2425)
Decimal('365.24250000000000682121026329696178436279296875')
>>> decimal.Decimal(146097) / decimal.Decimal(365.2425)
Decimal('399.9999999999999925296642496')
```

If you use a string, rather than a floating-point literal, as the argument to `Decimal`, you will get the rational denominator which produces the integer ratio 400. (`Decimal` can parse the string as an exact rational, rather than starting with a floating-point value that is already an approximation.)

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(146097) / decimal.Decimal('365.2425')
Decimal('4E+2')
```

Comment: I thought the same thing. But it seems the problem goes deeper. div is 365.2425. If you multiply that by 400, you have exactly 146097. So, the correct result, by decimal arithmetic, of 146097 / 365.2425 should be exactly 400.

Comment: This corresponds to the number of days in 400 years, by the way.

Comment: 0.2425 == 97/400; there is no exact floating-point equivalent to that value.

Comment: I've fixed the fraction, but the point remains:  the (rational) number 365.2425 does not have an exact floating-point representation. The floating point literal `365.2425` is *not* the rational number 3652425/10000000.

Comment: I almost get what's going on thanks to this answer - when you say "internal value" are you referring to `365.24250000000000682121026329696178436279296875`?

Comment: Perhaps worth to point out that 146097 *is* exactly represented as a floating point (given the last calculation), or also put it in a string to be absolutely clear.

Comment: Well, `146097` is an `int` literal, and one small enough to be represented precisely, so there's no need to have `Decimal` parse a string itself.

Comment: Ok, I finally understand! It was important for me to check this: `n = 399.9999999999999925296642496; print(n) # 400.0`. We can see that `decimal.Decimal` keeps more precision than python's built-in float.

Comment: Note that 365.2425 is *also* an approximation of how many days are in a year; the true value is something like 365.24219, which is why leap year rules get complicated. (Many people weren't  aware that 2000 would be a leap year, because it was the first century leap year since 1600.)